# removing dollar sign + matching curly braces multiple times in one line

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

Original line in file:

```
alarm_name = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"
```

Want this line without `${}`, `${}`, `${}`:

```
alarm_name = "var.environment-var.deployment-var.service_name-elb-healthyhosts"
```

With this `sed`: it removes 1st `${` and last `}`:

```
sed s'/\${\(.*\)}/\1/' filename
```

How can I remove the curly brackets pair-wise instead?

Comment: If you got an answer to your question then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```bsh
sed -E 's/\$\{([^}]+)\}/\1/g'
```

Demo:

```bsh
$ line='alarm_name = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"'
$ sed -E 's/\$\{([^}]+)\}/\1/g' <<<"$line"
alarm_name = "var.environment-var.deployment-var.service_name-elb-healthyhosts"
```

Comment: Perfect glenn: that is amazing! I will try it now

Answer (score 2):

With that input all you need is:

```
$ tr -d '${}' < file
alarm_name = "var.environment-var.deployment-var.service_name-elb-healthyhosts"
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that that won't work for.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `.*` also matches the intermediate `${}` between the initial `${` and the final `}`.

You may use `s/${\([^}]*\)}/\1/g` instead, which is almost what you have except that `.*` is replaced with `[^}]*`, which matches zero or more non-`}` characters.  The `/g` at the end repeats the substitution for all non-overlapping matches.

This would however not work on nested things like `${...${...}...}`, if you would ever have those.

Another approach:

Remove all the `${` and the `}` from the line:

```bsh
sed -e 's/${//g' -e 's/}//g' file
```

The benefit of the above command is that two simple regular expressions often are easier to understand and to maintain than one single more complex expression.  It also deals with nested `${}` strings, but lacks the ability to *pair up* `${` with `}`, so it would delete any `${` or `}` regardless of whether there's a corresponding `}` or `${` on the line.

If you want to do this only on lines starting with the string `alarm_name =`:

```bsh
sed -e '/^alarm_name =/!b' -e 's/${//g' -e 's/}//g' file
```

The `b` command branches to the end of the script and we use it here to bypass the substitutions if the line does not match `^alarm_name =`.

Testing:

```
$ cat file
alarm_name1 = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"
alarm_name = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"
alarm_name2 = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"
```

```
$ sed  -e '/^alarm_name =/!b' -e 's/${//g' -e 's/}//g' file
alarm_name1 = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"
alarm_name = "var.environment-var.deployment-var.service_name-elb-healthyhosts"
alarm_name2 = "${var.environment}-${var.deployment}-${var.service_name}-elb-healthyhosts"
```

---

Since you tagged your question with [ed](/questions/tagged/ed), this is how you would do that in the `ed` editor:

```
g/^alarm_name =/ s/${//g\
s/}//g
```

That is, for all lines matching `^alarm_name =` perform the two substitutions.

Or, as a scripted job from the command line:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' 'g/^alarm_name =/ s/${//g\' 's/}//g' ',p' 'Q' |
ed -s file
```

The `,p` followed by `Q` would output the contents of the modified file to standard output before quitting.  Use `w` and `q` (or `wq`) to write the changes back to the file instead.